# Difference between Tasking & optimizing compilers

Tags: embedded

What is the difference between tasking & optimizing compiler ?

Comment: This is a question about english comprehension and recognition of a proper-noun.  It is not "tasking compiler" but "Tasking Compiler" - "Tasking" is the name of the company whose compiler it is, not a _verb_ describing a compiler.   Pretty much all C and C++ compilers - especially  commercial ones - support optimisation, including Tasking's.  So there is no difference the questioning is like asking the difference between _Microsoft Word_ and a _word-processor_.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I got it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Optimise" is a verb, meaning "to make better". (Technically, it means "to make as good as possible" but in the context of "optimising compilers", "better" is as good as you get.)

[Tasking](https://www.tasking.com) is a company name. So a "tasking compiler" is a compiler made by that company.